# Android runOnUiThread causing memory leak

Tags: android, memory-leaks

I have a memory leak in my android application. It is a simple music player. At the bottom of the screen, I have a TextView which I use to display the elapsed time. It is updated in the thread below.

Each time I change the orientation, the heap size grows. From looking at the DDMS heap updates, it looks like my activity isn't being garbage collected. If, however, I comment out the 6 lines as I have done below, the GC keeps the heap at a fairly consistent size. Could you please let me know what it is that's causing this leak?

```
private void updateTimerAndSeekBar() {
    Thread updater = new Thread() {
        SeekBar seekbar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
        TextView timer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.currentTime);
        public void run() {

            while (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {

 //             runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
 //                 @Override
 //                 public void run() {
 //                     timer.setText(msToMins(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()));
 //                 }
 //             });

                try {
                    seekbar.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
                    sleep(1000);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    };
    updater.start();
}
```

Comment: Generate a heap dump via DDMS and use MAT to determine what is holding onto what.

Comment: The lines you've commented should actually have no effect since the activity is already kept alive by the existence of a running thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each time you change the orientation, Android creates and starts a new activity. The memory leak is due to the fact that the garbage collector cannot collect the old activity that's no longer needed since the separate thread is still running and - as an inner class - is holding onto the activity.

To get rid of the memory leak, you need to stop and end the separate thread when the activity is destroyed.

```
boolean stopThread;


private void updateTimerAndSeekBar() {

    stopThread = false;

    Thread updater = new Thread() {
        ...

        while (!stopThread && mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                try {
                    seekbar.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
                    sleep(1000);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    };
    updater.start();
}



protected void onDestroy () {
    stopThread = true;
    super.onDestroy();
}
```